# ios offline reading list not working

Tags: ios, safari, reading-list

Safari has a built in feature called reading list, for a few years I used it as an alternative to bookmarks for articles. When I was looking at storage usage I saw that safari has 200mb+ for offline reading list, therefore the pages must have been chaeched. However, when I turn my phone into airplane mode and try to access any of the pages from reading list it prompts me an error 'The operation couldn;t be completed. Operation not permitted' 
I tried to search the web for troubleshooting the reading list and the only suggestion I found was to make sure that enable downloading for reading list using cellular is on and it was on. I am not sure what I can do in order to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

On my iPhone 6 I need to turn off wifi and cellular data to read my reading list offline. If I have an Internet connection it will try  to load the page from the Internet connection instead of the cached page.

Comment: That is exactly why I mean. I would turn my phone into an airplane mode(both cellular and wifi off) and none of the reading list material is accessible

Answer (score 0):

Keep the tab open for a few moments. For larger sites, you may need to keep the tab open for a few moments to ensure that Safari saves everything. As long as the website isn't loading anymore, you're safe to close it.

Refer
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Websites-to-an-iPhone-or-iPad's-Reading-List-to-View-Offline

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this fixes the issue mentioned in the question?